# Elastic Search 6 returns duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates, elasticsearch-6

I have the code:

```
page = es.search(index = index, scroll  = scroll_exp, sort = "_doc", from_ = scroll_from, body = body)
```

I am trying to parallelize execution of this code. The code is executed on two different machines. But in both cases, pages that are returned are the same on both machines (although they should be different).
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Parallelize how?

Comment: I run on each of the machines the code above, with different scroll_from?
But the problem is that it always returns the same documents in Python(no matter what I set from_). 
When I use restful API everything passes alright.

Comment: So you are initializing a scroll on each machine then? In that case what you are seeing is the expected behavior, in effect you are doing the same search twice

Comment: On one machine I set the scrol_from = 0, on the other machine I set to be 100. It should not return the same results.

Comment: Whatever value I use for from_ I get always the same results. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I don't think scroll works that way. What you are looking for is sliced scroll, see here for an example https://hackernoon.com/parallel-scan-scroll-an-elasticsearch-index-db02583d10d1

Comment: But then, what is the use of from parameter?

Comment: Might be helpful to link the library you are using.  Scroll has no from parameter from its [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html).  Scroll works by returning the next result each time you hit it.

Comment: Even when I leave scroll out of a query, the same thing happens. 
So page = es.search(sort="_doc", from_ = scroll_from, boyd=body)
results each time in the same results (either from restful API or python).
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html
I am using elastic search 6.1.1.

Comment: That is the search offset, to get the next scroll you would have to consume the first

Comment: Forget about the scroll. page = es.search(sort="doc", from = from_val, boyd=body). It returns the same results no matter what I assign from_val to.

Comment: @sramalingam24 I have tried using the scroll with slices, but even in that case, I get the duplicates. 
(I change id value of slice and it still I get the same results, over and over)

Comment: Let's go back to the beginning, how many docs do you have? What are you setting as the size of the scroll and slices? Can you show your code?

Comment: Let's go back to the beginning, how many docs do you have? What are you setting as the size of the scroll and slices? Can you show your code?

Comment: Take a look here http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan I never use scroll in that way, but allways with helpers, it is better and suggested in the documentation, read client support paragraph https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: @Lupanoide How does this solve my problem? 
I am still unable to paginate my documents. 
If you mean to use scan I have read that it is deprecated.

Comment: @sramalingam24 I have let's say million(1'000'000) documents. I want to split the work on two separate machines. Therefore I need to do that using some kind of scroll. Problem is that neither of APIs on the site do not work at me.
I have even tried multislice : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html
But still, I get the same documents every time. 
"sort": [
    {
      "_uid": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type":"string"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "slice": {
        "field":"_uid",
        "id": 1,
        "max": 2

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch and python client are you using?

Comment: @sramalingam24 The problem is solved by leaving out the sort parameter in scroll search API (the slice API). Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @ЂорђеЖивановић Where have you read that scan helpers is deprecated? If you read around the elastic forum, you will discover that is the best practice according the elastic developers for scroll query in python

Comment: @ЂорђеЖивановић Good deal mate